# how to work function keys without pressing the fn key while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am using dell inspiron 5000 series laptop. It was very hard to press the `f10`,`f11` keys by pressing the `fn` key every time while debugging. Can you please give me the solution how can I be able to access directly the function keys without pressing `fn` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Fn" key is by default enabled in Dell laptops, you can disable Fn through BIOS setup. For this, reboot/restart you system and when DELL symbol shows, press F2 to enter into BIOS setup, select "POST Behaviour" ==> "Fn Lock Options". On the right side screen select "Lock Mode Disable/Standard".   It will disbale the "Fn" key and it won't interrupt while debugging.

Answer (score 21):

Although this is for a different version of Dell Laptop it took me ages to find the solution so thought I would share, as this post came up high on my google search.

On my laptop **XPS 15 9550** I had to press the **fn** key and the **f** key for example to refresh a page was **fn + F5**. Annoying.. to rectify the problem I looked in the BIOS as explained on this post but the option did not exist.

SOLUTION
Instead I needed to press "**Fn + Esc**" this locks the function key. now pressing **F5** refreshed the screen

Answer (score 8):

Yes this is a Bios setting, but you can simply toggle between them using `FN + ESC`

So in your case, hit `FN+ESC` once :)

Comment: wow it worked like charm...  I just edited undesired character from your comments to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly check whether your key board has "FnLock" key. It's usually with the "Esc" key. If you have ,great you don't need BIOS setup, follow the below steps-

1. Tap and hold the Fn key on your keyboard.
2. While holding the Fn key, tap the Fn lock key(Esc key) and then release both keys.
3. Done, now check f10, f11 for debugging or f5 for refresh , it will work , no need to do fn+f5.
4. To unlock the Function keys again, hold down the Fn key and hit fnlock/Esc together.

Answer (score 1):

From the menu go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. The right hand side will have a long list of commands (e.g. "Debug.StepOver") and fields for adding your own custom shortcuts.

Also I don't know about the Dell Inspiron but on my Surface Pro I can press Caps-Fn to keep it permanently on, so you might want to try that. I believe some laptops support it in the BIOS, so check there as well. Finally [this link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-function-key-behavior-windows-laptops) suggests that the Dell extensions to the Mobility Center allow you to change the behaviour there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would be in link below. You need to disable fn in bios.

http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/134495-Cant-use-my-F-keys-without-pressing-fn

Answer (score 0):

It worked for DELLL lattitude 5410 :

use fn key + escape key to toggle on/off function key lock.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).